# Custom div as cursor creates problems with the hover on links

Tags: javascript, css, mouse-cursor

I've a problem with a custom cursor created with an absolute div, with my test I realized that the custom div is directly positioned under the default cursor, then if I go hover a link I can't process my JS "mouseenter" because the default cursor is always hover only to the custom cursor... there is a way to fix it?

```
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>
```

Scss:

```
.custom-cursor {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border: 2px solid orange;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1080;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transition-duration: 100ms;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black;
   &.hover {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: rgba(#FFCC00,.5);
   }
}
```

Vanilla JS:

```
const cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
    
// Custom cursor follow the default cursor
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    cursor.setAttribute('style', 'top: '+(e.pageY - 10)+'px; left: ' +(e.pageX - 10)+'px;')
});

const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Custom cursor change style on hover links
for(let x of links) {

    x.addEventListener('mousenter', () => {
     cursor.classList.add('hover');
    });

    x.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
     cursor.classList.remove('hover');
    });
        
});
```

Comment: Edit and enclose your for loop in closing brackets tot he tilde code formatting and remove parenthesis from end of for loop closing brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none;` for the cursor-div - so that the hover event goes through. (you also forgot an **e** in "*mouseenter*"

**Working example:**

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
    
// Custom cursor follow the default cursor
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    cursor.setAttribute('style', 'top: '+(e.pageY - 10)+'px; left: ' +(e.pageX - 10)+'px;')
});

const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

// Custom cursor change style on hover links
for(let x of links) {

    x.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
     cursor.classList.add('hover');
    });

    x.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
     cursor.classList.remove('hover');
    });
        
}
```

```css
.custom-cursor {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border: 2px solid orange;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transition-duration: 100ms;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black;
   pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-cursor.hover {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: rgba(#FFCC00,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-cursor"></div>
<a href="#">troet</a>
<a href="#">quak</a>
<a href="#">miau</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

[You can enable clicking through elements by adding `pointer-events: none;` to your CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-div-to-underlying-elements)

```
.custom-cursor {
   pointer-events: none; /*don't interact with this div*/
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border: 2px solid orange;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1080;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transition-duration: 100ms;
   transition-timing-function: ease-out;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black;
   &.hover {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background: rgba(#FFCC00,.5);
   }
}
```